# Find volume of cone in sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I can't understand why the projection of those two objects on plane $xy$ gives that the angle's range from -90 degress to 90 degrees. why not from 0 to 360?

[image]

Edit: from my understanding, if $x > 0$ then $cos > 0$ and then I will understand how the range is computed. but how did they show that $x > 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*But how did they show that $x > 0$?*

> Observe that $x^2+y^2+z^2=2x$ implies $x\geq0.$

Comment: This is brilliant! Because $r^2 = 2x$ thus $x = r^2 / 2$ and $r \ge 0$. Thank you!

Comment: @Ilan Aizelman WS You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is the famous Viviani scenario. Usually the unit sphere is centered at origin and cylinder axis displaced by unity. Here cylinder axis is z-axis and sphere is displaced by unity distance along x-axis.

By sketching them you note there is  *no surface* outside the $\theta $ interval $ - \pi/2 , \pi/2 .$